# Combining text and hyperlink in excel

Tags: excel

I have text in column B and hyperlink in Column C. I need to concatenate these in column D. But the hyperlink disappears on concatenation in Column D. Cannot find anything online. Can someone please help?

```
B                               C   
Quaterly Results are here:      https://bloomberg.com   

D
Quaterly Results are here : https://bloomberg.com
```

I have used the following formulas , none works:

```
=B2 & "" & HYPERLINK(C2)
=CONCATENATE(B2,"", HYPERLINK(C2))
```

Comment: You can't hyperlink the partial contents of a cell. Why not just get rid of column C and use the URL as the hyperlink target in column B?

Comment: I am not hyperlinking partial content. Just trying to join two cells with one having only hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

try this formal

`=HYPERLINK(C2,CONCATENATE(B2,C2))`

C1 should be the link

B1 should be name for the hyperlink

[image]

Comment: please make it as answer if it fixes the issue